# how to create a button in the first blank cell of a column

Tags: excel, vba, button

i'm trying to create a button with the following:

```
Selection.Characters.Text = "Hide"
With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=4).Font
.Name = "Calibri"
.FontStyle = "Regular"
.Size = 11
.Strikethrough = False
.Superscript = False
.Subscript = False
.OutlineFont = False
.Shadow = False
.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
.ColorIndex = 1
```

i wish for the button to appear in a blank cell on the end of column B, after cell B4 (cells B1-B3 may not always have a value as well)

thank you

Comment: but your code doesn't create a button. Please, show a snippet of your work which do so.

Comment: KazJaw is right. not unless you only want to format the first blank cell.

Comment: thanks @KazJaw, - the above is just the specifications of the button... i've found a couple of codes to create buttons, and a couple of codes to select the next available blank cell in the column, but they just don't seem to work together... the above code was recorded when i first tried to copy and paste an existing button into a new cell, but that didn't work as well - it just ended up pasting over the existing cell even though the rest of the functions seems to work, just not in the write placing...

Answer (score 2):

just to share, i ended up finding the code, was a lot simpler than i thought...:

```
Dim btn As Button
Dim rng As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = .Range("B4").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set btn = .Buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, 57.75, 34.5)
With btn
.Caption = "Hide"
.OnAction = "Macro2"
End With
End With
```

i guess the specification of the font & stuff wasn't that important...

Comment: you can actually add the code in your question to format the button.